# how to remove the xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" from my wsdl

Tags: web-services, wsdl, spring-ws

Hi I am replacing an old web service running on JBOSS with a new web service running in spring on Tomcat using spring contract first web service.  Everything is great the web service looks identical except the spring has the WSDL name space where as the WSDL generated by JBOSS doesn't have the namespace.  Is there a way to generate the WSDL without the namespace?

Answer (score 0):

The expression is simply binding the prefix wsdl to 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/', which is the namespace of the wsdl elements.  Given that the jboss wsdl is working and is identical in all respects save that prefix binding, the spring-based document will work fine with or without the extra declaration.

This is to say...I do not know whether it is possible to force the spring/tomcat machinery to drop the declaration, but the value in doing so is negligible.